# Only variables should be passed by reference : PHP Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following errors in the code below:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Only variables should be passed by reference

Filename: codeigniter/Common.php

Please help me.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
     * @link        http://codeigniter.com
     * @since       Version 1.0
     * @filesource
     */

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
* Determines if the current version of PHP is greater then the supplied value
*
* Since there are a few places where we conditionally test for PHP > 5
* we'll set a static variable.
*
* @access   public
* @param    string
* @return   bool
*/
function is_php($version = '5.0.0')
{
    static $_is_php;
    $version = (string)$version;

    if ( ! isset($_is_php[$version]))
    {
        $_is_php[$version] = (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, $version) < 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    return $_is_php[$version];
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Tests for file writability
 *
 * is_writable() returns TRUE on Windows servers when you really can't write to 
 * the file, based on the read-only attribute.  is_writable() is also unreliable
 * on Unix servers if safe_mode is on. 
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  void
 */
function is_really_writable($file)
{   
    // If we're on a Unix server with safe_mode off we call is_writable
    if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/' AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == FALSE)
    {
        return is_writable($file);
    }

    // For windows servers and safe_mode "on" installations we'll actually
    // write a file then read it.  Bah...
    if (is_dir($file))
    {
        $file = rtrim($file, '/').'/'.md5(rand(1,100));

        if (($fp = @fopen($file, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE)) === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        fclose($fp);
        @chmod($file, DIR_WRITE_MODE);
        @unlink($file);
        return TRUE;
    }
    elseif (($fp = @fopen($file, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE)) === FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    fclose($fp);
    return TRUE;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
* Class registry
*
* This function acts as a singleton.  If the requested class does not
* exist it is instantiated and set to a static variable.  If it has
* previously been instantiated the variable is returned.
*
* @access   public
* @param    string  the class name being requested
* @param    bool    optional flag that lets classes get loaded but not instantiated
* @return   object
*/
function &load_class($class, $instantiate = TRUE)
{
    static $objects = array();

    // Does the class exist?  If so, we're done...
    if (isset($objects[$class]))
    {
        return $objects[$class];
    }

    // If the requested class does not exist in the application/libraries
    // folder we'll load the native class from the system/libraries folder. 
    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'libraries/'.config_item('subclass_prefix').$class.EXT))
    {
        require(BASEPATH.'libraries/'.$class.EXT);
        require(APPPATH.'libraries/'.config_item('subclass_prefix').$class.EXT);
        $is_subclass = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'libraries/'.$class.EXT))
        {
            require(APPPATH.'libraries/'.$class.EXT);
            $is_subclass = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            require(BASEPATH.'libraries/'.$class.EXT);
            $is_subclass = FALSE;
        }
    }

    if ($instantiate == FALSE)
    {
        $objects[$class] = TRUE;
        return $objects[$class];
    }

    if ($is_subclass == TRUE)
    {
        $name = config_item('subclass_prefix').$class;

        $objects[$class] =& instantiate_class(new $name());
        return $objects[$class];
    }

    $name = ($class != 'Controller') ? 'CI_'.$class : $class;

    $objects[$class] =& instantiate_class(new $name());
    return $objects[$class];
}

/**
 * Instantiate Class
 *
 * Returns a new class object by reference, used by load_class() and the DB class.
 * Required to retain PHP 4 compatibility and also not make PHP 5.3 cry.
 *
 * Use: $obj =& instantiate_class(new Foo());
 * 
 * @access  public
 * @param   object
 * @return  object
 */
function &instantiate_class(&$class_object)
{
    return $class_object;
}

/**
* Loads the main config.php file
*
* @access   private
* @return   array
*/
function &get_config()
{
    static $main_conf;

    if ( ! isset($main_conf))
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'config/config'.EXT))
        {
            exit('The configuration file config'.EXT.' does not exist.');
        }

        require(APPPATH.'config/config'.EXT);

        if ( ! isset($config) OR ! is_array($config))
        {
            exit('Your config file does not appear to be formatted correctly.');
        }

        $main_conf[0] =& $config;
    }
    return $main_conf[0];
}

/**
* Gets a config item
*
* @access   public
* @return   mixed
*/
function config_item($item)
{
    static $config_item = array();

    if ( ! isset($config_item[$item]))
    {
        $config =& get_config();

        if ( ! isset($config[$item]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $config_item[$item] = $config[$item];
    }

    return $config_item[$item];
}


/**
* Error Handler
*
* This function lets us invoke the exception class and
* display errors using the standard error template located
* in application/errors/errors.php
* This function will send the error page directly to the
* browser and exit.
*
* @access   public
* @return   void
*/
function show_error($message, $status_code = 500)
{
    $error =& load_class('Exceptions');
    echo $error->show_error('An Error Was Encountered', $message, 'error_general', $status_code);
    exit;
}


/**
* 404 Page Handler
*
* This function is similar to the show_error() function above
* However, instead of the standard error template it displays
* 404 errors.
*
* @access   public
* @return   void
*/
function show_404($page = '')
{
    $error =& load_class('Exceptions');
    $error->show_404($page);
    exit;
}


/**
* Error Logging Interface
*
* We use this as a simple mechanism to access the logging
* class and send messages to be logged.
*
* @access   public
* @return   void
*/
function log_message($level = 'error', $message, $php_error = FALSE)
{
    static $LOG;

    $config =& get_config();
    if ($config['log_threshold'] == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    $LOG =& load_class('Log');
    $LOG->write_log($level, $message, $php_error);
}


/**
 * Set HTTP Status Header
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   int     the status code
 * @param   string  
 * @return  void
 */
function set_status_header($code = 200, $text = '')
{
    $stati = array(
                        200 => 'OK',
                        201 => 'Created',
                        202 => 'Accepted',
                        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
                        204 => 'No Content',
                        205 => 'Reset Content',
                        206 => 'Partial Content',

                        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
                        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
                        302 => 'Found',
                        304 => 'Not Modified',
                        305 => 'Use Proxy',
                        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',

                        400 => 'Bad Request',
                        401 => 'Unauthorized',
                        403 => 'Forbidden',
                        404 => 'Not Found',
                        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
                        406 => 'Not Acceptable',
                        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
                        408 => 'Request Timeout',
                        409 => 'Conflict',
                        410 => 'Gone',
                        411 => 'Length Required',
                        412 => 'Precondition Failed',
                        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
                        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
                        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
                        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
                        417 => 'Expectation Failed',

                        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
                        501 => 'Not Implemented',
                        502 => 'Bad Gateway',
                        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
                        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
                        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
                    );

    if ($code == '' OR ! is_numeric($code))
    {
        show_error('Status codes must be numeric', 500);
    }

    if (isset($stati[$code]) AND $text == '')
    {               
        $text = $stati[$code];
    }

    if ($text == '')
    {
        show_error('No status text available.  Please check your status code number or supply your own message text.', 500);
    }

    $server_protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : FALSE;
 if (substr(php_sapi_name(), 0, 3) == 'cgi')
    {
        header("Status: {$code} {$text}", TRUE);
    }
    elseif ($server_protocol == 'HTTP/1.1' OR $server_protocol == 'HTTP/1.0')
    {
        header($server_protocol." {$code} {$text}", TRUE, $code);
    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.1 {$code} {$text}", TRUE, $code);
    }
}


/**
* Exception Handler
*
* This is the custom exception handler that is declaired at the top
* of Codeigniter.php.  The main reason we use this is permit
* PHP errors to be logged in our own log files since we may
* not have access to server logs. Since this function
* effectively intercepts PHP errors, however, we also need
* to display errors based on the current error_reporting level.
* We do that with the use of a PHP error template.
*
* @access   private
* @return   void
*/
function _exception_handler($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{   
     // We don't bother with "strict" notices since they will fill up
     // the log file with information that isn't normally very
     // helpful.  For example, if you are running PHP 5 and you
     // use version 4 style class functions (without prefixes
     // like "public", "private", etc.) you'll get notices telling
     // you that these have been deprecated.

    if ($severity == E_STRICT)
    {
        return;
    }

    $error =& load_class('Exceptions');

    // Should we display the error?
    // We'll get the current error_reporting level and add its bits
    // with the severity bits to find out.

    if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity)
    {
        $error->show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
    }

    // Should we log the error?  No?  We're done...
    $config =& get_config();
    if ($config['log_threshold'] == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    $error->log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
}



/* End of file Common.php */
/* Location: ./system/codeigniter/Common.php */
```

Comment: It's only a notice... and if you go through the code you'll notice PHP 4 backward compatibility notes in the comments.

Comment: whats is the line number

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?